# number of a book in a series

Tags: idiom-requests

I am wondering if there is a generic term to refer to the number of a book within a series, but not so generic as *number*.

As an analogy with TV Series, we can use the term *episode*, for example: episode 1 of Top Gear Season 2.

It seems there are some specific terms depending of the type of books, for example *issue* for comic books: issue 3 of The Sandman.

Comment: For a *generic* word, you can simply use ***entry***. It applies to any type of series, not just books. (But it's not clear from the question if you want a word that's specific to books. If so, the current answer is good.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The words **book** or **volume** can be used in this manner. Two examples:

> [*Foundation and Empire*] is the second **book** in the Foundation Series. [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foundation_and_Empire)
>
> *The Two Towers* is the second **volume** of J. R. R. Tolkien's high fantasy novel *The Lord of the Rings*. [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Two_Towers)

Some users differentiate between the two: using **volume** may connote that the larger work is one long story, perhaps published in multiple parts. So for a book series where the stories are more self-contained, **book** would likely be more appropriate.

The word **book** has many related uses: according to definition 4 in the OED entry, a book is "a main subdivision of a larger written work". This definition occurs in uses like "books of the Bible" or "books of the Iliad". While the Iliad and Bible are usually published as one volume, they can still be separated into books.

Comment: *This book, published in two volumes called "books" by the author, is a treatment of everything from the origin of our ideas to how they are to be divided.* https://www.hibooks.com/discover/audiobook/treatise-of-human-nature-volume-2-a

Comment: Things can get pretty muddied sometimes.